# What does IsPostBack actually mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am interested to know what specifically Page.IsPostBack means. I am fully aware of it's day to day use in a standard ASP.NET page, that it indicates that the user is 
submitting data back to the server side. See [Page:IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

But given this HTML

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="default.aspx">
         <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the Submit button, the pages Page_Load method is invoked, but the Page.IsPostBack is returning false. I don't want to add `runat=server`.

How do I tell the difference between the pages first load, and a Request caused by the client hitting submit?

**update**
I've added in `<input type="text" value="aa" name="ctrl" id="ctrl" />` so the Request.Form has an element, and Request.HTTPMethod is POST, but IsPostBack is still false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to extend the ASP.NET Page class, "override" the IsPostBack property and let all your pages derive from the extended page.

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public new bool IsPostBack
    {
        get 
        { 
          return 
            Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0 &&
            Request.RequestType.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: that would actually be more suited for a property named "IsPost".

Comment: Editted to include "Request.Form.Keys.Count" I can then look up the value from the textbox using Request.Form["ctrl"]

Answer (score 12):

Check the Request.Form collection to see if it is non-empty.  Only a POST will have data in the Request.Form collection.  Of course, if there is no form data then the request is indistinguishable from a GET.

As to the question in your title, IsPostBack is set to true when the request is a POST from a server-side form control.  Making your form client-side only, defeats this.

Comment: +1 from me.  I was running a bit behind remembering that Request.Forms was where you'd pull raw input form data.  This is the right answer.  I'm still curious, though, why Ian isn't setting up page handling.

Comment: @Mark - Im being "hardcore" and doing everything myself. Don't ask why :-)

Comment: +1 @tvanfosson - I marked the other question as answer, because I can also include "Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0"

Answer (score 1):

In the example that you include in your question, there is no viewstate involved; there is no way for the server to link this request to a previous request of the page and treat them as a unit. The request resulting in clicking the button will look like any other random request coming in to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a you could view a PostBack as a combination of:

1. HTTP request method equals "POST"
2. HTTP header HTTP_REFERER equals the current URL

That's not 100% foolproof tho, it does not take into account any state of any kind (which you probably want even if you don't know it) but it is a **post**, **back** to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the headers to see if your *input* controls are returning a value (using Request.Forms as tvanfosson points out).  However, the really big question is why you would *not* want to add runat=server.  The entire page processing edifice implemented by ASP.NET (except MVC) depends on processing the page output through the server to set up the appropriate client-side code for callbacks, etc.