# Get text from asp:textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, textbox

I am writing ASP.NET project in C#.

The UpdateUserInfo.aspx page consists textboxes and button. In pageLoad() method I set some text to the textbox and when button is cicked I get the new value of textbox and write it into DB.

The problem is even if I have changed the value of textbox textbox.Text() method returns the old value of textbox ("sometext") and write this into DB.

Here the methods:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.text = "sometext";
}

void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    String textbox_text = textbox.text();// this is still equals "somevalue", even I change the textbox value
    writeToDB(textbox_text);
}
```

So, how to make textbox to appear with somevalue initially, but when user changes this value getText method return the new changed value and write this into DB?

Comment: You can read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829249/what-does-ispostback-actually-mean

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       textbox.text = "sometext";
    }
}
```

Postback is setting the textboxs text property back to `"somevalue"` on button click, you'll want to set the value only once as above.

Postback explained:

> In the context of ASP web development, a postback is another name for
>   HTTP POST. In an interactive webpage, the contents of a form are sent
>   to the server for processing some information. Afterwards, the server
>   sends a new page back to the browser.
>
> This is done to verify passwords for logging in, process an on-line
>   order form, or other such tasks that a client computer cannot do on
>   its own. This is not to be confused with refresh or back actions taken
>   by the buttons on the browser.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback)

Reading up on [View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) will also be helpful in understanding how it all fits together.

Comment: So Btn_Click method updates page,i.e. Page_load also is called when button is clicked yes? And PostBack is used to inform that the button has called Page_load method. Am I right?

Comment: The Button click event causes a postback. Page load is called when the page loads, either for the first time or due to a postback. Your line of code is being applied the first time the page loads + for all subsequent postbacks, so your new value is never set. In future, if you only want some code to be run once when the page first loads and not on postbacks, you must place it inside the `!Page.IsPostBack` block.

Comment: Many thanks, this was really confusing me why my textbox would never have any text in its property, even though the user had entered some.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If (!IsPostBack) 
{   
textbox.text = "sometext";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually on page load `textbox` is re-initilized

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           textbox.text = "sometext";
        }
    }
    void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        String textbox_text = textbox.text;
        writeToDB(textbox_text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check Page PostBack in the Page Load Event....