# ASP NET force TextBox update or unfocus

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox

I have a basic ASP NET C# TextBox and Button search setup. When the Button is pressed it sets a Session variable as the TextBox contents and then updates a Gridview Datasource using the Session variable.

My issue is that the search Button must be pressed twice after entering text, as the TextBox Text value doesn't update until the user clicks off box.

Is there a way to programmatically force the TextBox to update while it is still selected or alternatively force the user out of the text box so the value updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2 possible issues

#### 1. Update in wrong place

I think the issue is that your focus is on the textbox, then clicking the search button:

1. Invokes the search button click event
2. Removes the `Focus` from the textbox, which invokes the `FocusLost` which updates the variable.

Thus the variable still has the old value.

Instead, in your button, you can update directly:

```
string _searchText;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _searchText = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
    // do something with _searchText
}
```

#### 2. PostBack is disabled

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948360/get-text-from-asptextbox)

Comment: Thanks. I knew the issue was the focus I just forgot the term to describe it. Using Server.HtmlEncode solved my problem.