# How to use postback in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my webpage I want to use IsPostBack. The reason to use it is to load the page with the updated details after the user pressed edit and updated some information. Is there any other good way to implement it? In case if you know some good methods please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829249/what-does-ispostback-actually-mean/829269#829269

Comment: Could anyone please explain it more clearly. I am new to ASP.net

Comment: If you're just starting, then why are you looking for alternate methods of implementing things? Just use what's in the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I use IsPostback to make sure that I only perform certain actions once during `Page_Load()`. Typically, these are things that I don't need or want to do more than once.

```
if (!IsPostback)
{
     PopulateADropDownBox();
     this.SomeTextbox.Text = "first time value";
}
```

In this example, it's pointless to repopulate the dropdown; it will remain populated across Postbacks, therefore I only need to do it once. Likewise, someone may have altered the text in `SomeTextbox` and if I set it back to the original value that was in it when the page loaded, I'll have thrown out the user's input.

Answer (score 1):

First read Page Life Cycle.

While inserting / updating debugger follow path Like It goes to page_load ( If you are seeting values to page_load then ) then Events

Example :

Updating gridview ...

public .. Page_load(....)

{

```
If(!ispostBack)
{
 setpageValue();
}
```

}

button1_click(...)

```
{   

updateData();

}
```

Here ISpostBack plays important role of different operations;... try it...